# 7year old is toilet trained but insists on nappy for bedtime

Tags: toilet-training

My 7 year old ids completely toilet trained day and night but she insists on wearing training pants to bed . tried all ways but she becomes very distressed at the thought of not wearing one

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site.  Are you asking how to convince her to stop?  Or are you asking something else?  Can you clarify?

Comment: If the issue is the expense for an item she does not need, one possible alternative would be a reusable (cloth) version that is regularly washed like the rest of her laundry. If she is still wrong the bed, there is a whole different set of approaches. Can you clarify what your concern/goal is?

Answer (score 5):

I would not worry. I would let the child have her training pants if she feels comfort in that. I would allow her even to use the same training pants for a few nights in a row (if clean) and suggesting she use the training pants over some underpants in order for them to keep clean longer.

I would try to start treating the training pants like any other clothing, and try to keep the same one in the room (again only if clean), letting it become old and broken.

Comment: I second this.  She is obviously anxious about the possibility of wetting herself at night, and simply telling her that she won't isn't going to convince her otherwise.  Only time will do that.  And if you convince her to not wear the pants and she (maybe out of anxiety) does have an accident, you will have shaken her trust in your judgment.  Not worth the risk...let her decide when she is ready to let go.

Comment: I fully agree with that. If she wants to keep it and that makes her more secure, I don't see no harm. She will probably realize very soon how "baby-ish" this is and drop it herself...